# How do you organize your business requirements and tests?

Tags: testing

as of right now i'm working at place where's there's a lot of legacy codes and pretty much no useful documentation.

and most of the time we just treat business requirements as whatever that is already implemented previously.

i'm looking for any tools or useful method to keep all the requirements for future use and for regression testing mostly.

i'm thinking of maybe linking them up to tests/unit test too so that the business requirements are linked directly to the coding logic.

Any good tools or resources to get me started?
thanks~

### Updates

As of now i'm making things simple on myself by writing use case and then create some simple use case diagram using [this awesome tool](http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/usecase/samples) and then convert each use case into a test plan. The test plan is meant for the end user, thus i just make it into a simple step by step flow. I had plans to automate this part using selenium but it wasn't working that well on our website and was taking too long. It's a bit TDD, but i think it create simple understandable goal for both end user and the developer, i hope.

So for now it's just excel and doc file, lugged into the project doc folder and check into cvs/svn doomed to be outdated and be forgotten :P

Comment: lol, did u mean the massacre?

Answer (score 0):

Business requirements can be well capture in **[FitNess tests](http://www.beroux.com/english/articles/fitnesse-system-testing/)**. As for [Unit Test](http://www.beroux.com/english/articles/boost_unit_testing/) they sur help, and but both together in [continuous integration like Hudson](http://www.beroux.com/english/articles/hudson-continuous-integration/) to detect regression ASAP.

PS: Sorry pretty much all links go to some articles I wrote because I'm also interested in that subject.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some methods/systems that I have used

**HP Quality Center**
Big and bulky. Not very agile but it works and has a lot of feautres.
It's used in many larger corporations and if you can afford you can get great support from HP
https://h10078.www1.hp.com/cda/hpms/display/main/hpms_content.jsp?zn=bto&cp=1-11-127-24%5E1131_4000_100__

**Bugzilla-Testopia**
Open Source test case management extension for Bugzilla, managed by Mozilla. Which is good enough in my book to give it a try.
http://www.mozilla.org/projects/testopia/

**Excel/Open Office Calc**
Just do everything in spreadsheets and link between them.
Very flexible, everybody knows how to use them and you propbably have the software in your organization already.

**Other Open Source Solutions**
List of 15+ Open Source Test Management Tools
http://www.jayphilips.com/2009/09/10/15-open-source-test-management-tools/